# Is it not possible to convert a std::vector<T> to an std::initializer_list<T>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector, initializer-list

I would have thought that one could do this?  Yet, it doesn't seem to be the case.  Why?  Or am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fn(std::initializer_list<int> i)
{
  for(int ivalue:i)
  {
    cout << ivalue << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  fn({1,2,3});
  fn(vector<int>{4,5,6})
  return 0;
}
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/FtDLFw)

The reason I ask this is because I have a class that takes an initializer list and I've derived from it but need to massage the initializer list prior to passing it to the base. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: A vector is not an initializer_list. Both are ranges though, you can use begin/end or for loops on both and share code that way.

Comment: Yeah, I know that a vector isn't an initializer list, but surly it's convertible?

Comment: no it's not (convertable). And it shouldn't be. `initializer_list` was created so that containers like vector to be created from them, not the other way around.

Comment: @bolov, So how can I modify the call to the base constructor? Unless there's another way then using a vector, then it's a too constrained idiom.

Comment: @Adrian initializer_list is meant specifically for passing a list spelled with { and }. The abstract concept that unifies both is a range. Some people are working on a class (with `view` in the same) that would be constructible from any range and could play the role you want. That's not at all what initializer_list is supposed to be.

Comment: Good grief, reading this questionI just realized that it's now perfectly legal in C++ to write bash-style loops with arbitrary values going into the loop counter... `for(int i : {3, 5, 11, 20}) ...`

Comment: its not convertable because an initializer_list of int expression is comile-time constexpr, and a vector of int is run-time object. these two just conflicts.  In your case, you may change your constructor to template function to make both happy :http://ideone.com/WkGiTr

Comment: let me rephrase: `initializer_list` is meant to be used as a... well... initializer, not as a stand alone container. You shouldn't use `initializer_list` as the container of choice. `initializer_list` is just that: a way to initialize other containers.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the old ways are the best ways: just pass in the range:

```
void fn(std::initializer_list<int> i) {
    fn(i.begin(), i.end());
}

template <typename It>
void fn(It it, It end) {
    for (; it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}

fn({1, 2, 3});

std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
fn(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

For your specific question... Your constructor that takes the initializer list has to iterate over it anyway, just delegate that operation to an iterator-pair constructor:

```
Foo(std::initializer_list<T> init)
: Foo(init.begin(), init.end())
{ }

template <typename It>
Foo(It it, It end)
{
    // here the magic happens
}
```

Comment: You can also pass a "new-style" range, no need to split into a pair of iterators. This way, the body of `fn` can be kept as in the OP.

Comment: @MarcGlisse What is this new style range you speak of?

Comment: `template<class R>void fn(R const&r){for(auto value:r)cout<<value<<endl;}`

Comment: @MarcGlisse, oh that.  I thought you were referring to some type of class.

Comment: @Marc In C++1z that becomes `for (value: r)`, where `value` is `auto&&`.

Comment: @remyabel Not likely - that change ([N3994 "Range-Based For-Loops: The Next Generation"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm)) was [rejected in Urbana](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html#CWG15).

Answer (score 0):

C++ lacks a simple "view into a contiguous block of memory" class.  Here is one:

```
template<class T>
struct ro_array_view {
  T const* b_ = nullptr;
  T const* e_ = nullptr;
  size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  T const* begin() const { return b_; }
  T const* end() const { return e_; }
  T const& operator[](size_t i)const{ return begin()[i]; }
  bool empty()const{return begin()==end();}
  T const& front() const { return *begin(); }
  T const& back() const { return *std::prev(end()); }

  // annoying numbers of constructors:
  struct from_container_tag {};
  template<class O>
  ro_array_view( from_container_tag, O&& o ):
    ro_array_view(o.data(), o.size()) {}

  template<class...A>
  ro_array_view( std::vector<T,A...> const& o )
    :ro_array_view(from_container_tag{},o) {}
  ro_array_view( std::initializer_list<T> const& il )
    :ro_array_view(il.begin(), il.size()) {}
  template<size_t N>
  ro_array_view( std::array<T, N> const& o )
    :ro_array_view(from_container_tag{},o) {}
  template<size_t N>
  ro_array_view( std::array<T const, N> const& o )
    :ro_array_view(from_container_tag{},o) {}
  template<size_t N>
  ro_array_view( T const(&arr)[N] )
    :array_view( arr, N ) {}

  // penultimate constructor of most paths:
  ro_array_view( T const* arr, size_t N )
    :ro_array_view(arr, arr+N) {}
  // terminal constructor:
  ro_array_view( T const* b, T const* e )
    :b_(b),e_(e) {}
};
```

now simply take an `ro_array_view<int>` and it will convert the incoming argument to a pair of pointers, and expose a read-only container-like interface to it.

This seems overkill at first glance, but you'll find it is a very common function to use.  A huge chunk of functions that take a `std::vector<T> const&` should instead take a `ro_array_view<T>` by value.

A non-`ro_array_view` is a bit different (its methods are all mostly `const` still, but it stores `T*` not `T const*`.  I'd call it `rw_array_view`, then make `array_view` a `using` alias that conditionally uses `ro_array_view` or `rw_array_view`.  Add in a converting ctor from `rw_array_view` to `ro_array_view` to finish up the project.

I have two different types, instead of one, because `rw_array_view` and `ro_array_view` have different constructors from some container.  a `rw_array_view<T>` can be constructed from a `vector<T,A...>&`, while a `ro_array_view<T>` requires `vector<T, A...>const&`.  `std::array` is a bit worse because `const T` is a valid type to have in a `std::array`.  And `ro_array_view` is used in most uses, with `rw_array_view` being useful for cases where we want to modify the contents without modifying the container.